# Why CopyOnWriteArrayList use local variable referenced to instance variable?

Tags: java

Following is jdk concurrent's definition of `CopyOnWriteArrayList`:

```
private volatile transient Object[] array;
transient final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();


public boolean add(E e) {
        final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
        lock.lock();
        try {
            Object[] elements = getArray();
            int len = elements.length;
            Object[] newElements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, len + 1);
            newElements[len] = e;
            setArray(newElements);
            return true;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

Why `add` function defines another lock(`final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;`) which also referenced to the instance variable(`lock`) as local virable, instead of directly using the instance variable?

Can `add` function be implemented as:

```
int len = array.length;
Object[] newElements = Arrays.copyOf(array, len + 1);
newElements[len] = o;
array = newElements;
```